# TimerTask vs ScheduledThreadPool vs HashedThreadWheel

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

This is one more `TimerTask` vs `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` vs netty's `HashedWheelTimer` question.

I was looking at play framework documentation. There is a method called `timeout` in `play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise`. Basically it schedule's tasks to be executed. Here is the implementation:

```
private val timer = new java.util.Timer()

def timeout[A](message: => A, duration: Long, unit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] = {
val p = Promise[A]()
timer.schedule( new java.util.TimerTask{
  def run(){
    p.completeWith(Future(message)(ec))
  }
},unit.toMillis(duration) )
p.future
```

}

Why did they use `TimerTask` here when `SCTE` is a better implementation. Why not netty's `HashedWheelTimer` when even Akka uses it for its `scheduler`? How is one superior to another.